# HTML5 Boilerplate Options

Tags: html, html5boilerplate

I am trying to build my first HTML5 site. I started off trying to use the HTML5 Boilerplate, however that requires me to have access to the htaccess file. I am building this on a client's existing server and they can't give me that access. I really like the boilerplate's features as far as the css setup goes and all. I want something that will make it that easy to start my project. I don't want to have to code it from scratch. Guidance?

Comment: You don't need to use _all_ of HTML5 Boilerplate, use the **Custom Boilerplate** button to get just the bits you want.

Comment: I don't think I know enough about it to be able to do that. I'm really a designer not a developer. I know basic HTML and a better than basic css. Can you explain this any better? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however that requires me to have access to the htaccess file

Why does it *require* this? Is something not working? The .htaccess file should not be required for the HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

As steveax mentioned:

1. Go to http://html5boilerplate.com/
2. Click at "Customize Boilerplate"
3. Uncheck ".htaccess" (and you probably want to uncheck "Ant Build Script", too)
4. Download!